# How can i consume a batches of messages from rabbitmq?

Tags: go, rabbitmq

Before consuming i set

```
consumeChannel.Qos(5,0,false)
```

but still getting only one message, not a pack of five.
what i'm doing wrong?

full code:

```
consumeChannel.Qos(5,0,false)
msgs, _ := consumeChannel.Consume("ticks", "", false, false, false, false, nil, )

for d := range msgs {
    println("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
    println("Done")
    //here will be some extra multiple message handling
    //d.Ack(false)
}
```

Comment: Please share some code so we can help you. Normally, you send a "prefetchSize" with desired number of messages that you want to consume.

Comment: @RecigioPoffo added code, first parameter is "prefetchCount" isn't it what i need?

Comment: Qos(prefetchCount, prefetchSize int, global bool) -> try set the second one too.

https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp

Comment: @RecigioPoffo when setting second application fails with error "channel/connection is not open"

Comment: Are there actually 5 ready messages in the queue? Doing a packet capture on port 5672 could reveal what's happening.

Comment: @LukeBakken, yes, there are ~1 million messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but still getting only one message, not a pack of five. what i'm doing wrong?

You don't understand how RabbitMQ and QoS / prefetch works ([docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#channel-qos-prefetch)), or how it interacts with the `range` operator of the Go client.

QoS does not mean "send messages in batches", it sets a limit to the number of unacknowledged messages on a channel. If you were to remove the `d.Ack` call in your code and run the `for` loop indefinitely, it would only run for 5 iterations, then stop, because RabbitMQ would have stopped delivering messages by then to your consumer.

I haven't reviewed the code, but I assume the Go client you're using is written in such a way that, as soon as a message has been received and decoded, it is delivered to the `msgs` channel. When you ack the message in the loop, it indicates to RabbitMQ that one more message can be delivered to that channel.

I suggest re-writing your code to keep track of how many messages have been delivered via the `msgs` channel, do your work, and then use a [multiple acknowledgement](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#consumer-acks-multiple-parameter) to ack them all at the same time.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, thanks a lot!
So what can be a solution to take a batches of messages?

Comment: But messages just keep coming from channel, and i can't just stop the flow, am i right ?

Comment: @George - you really need to read the documentation, and try my suggestions, rather than continue to ask questions that have already been answered. For instance, I wrote "...if you were to remove the d.Ack call in your code and run the for loop indefinitely, it would only run for 5 iterations, then stop" - did you *try* that???

Comment: Did it work as expected? Did it not work? I can't continue to help if I have to keep asking for more information.

Comment: If you could share your solution in a repository or gist, that would help out everyone else that reads this question in the future.